# how to remove first two segments of a url string in java?

Tags: java, android

if I have a url string like "http://www.google.com" how can I convert that to just "google.com" in java? Im assuming there is a way to parse this using a function in java, any help will go a long way thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993649/how-to-normalize-a-url-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object and then use the methods provided to grab whatever you need.

Example:

```
URL myURL= new URL("http://www.google.com");
String host = myURL.getHost();
```

Comment: Looks like that guy removed his hacky solution to this problem lol

Comment: It was a 15 year old kid with a bunch of substring methods. I hope he at least took the advice we gave him.

Comment: What about querystrings following host?

Answer (score 3):

Using the [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) class, there's a method called `getHost()` that will do exactly that.

It's much easier to use a built in method, rather than rolling your own (you need to be aware of multiple sub domains, different protocol like https).

Comment: Thank you, at least someone else also has the sense to provide a REAL solution and not some hacky substring function.