# Java How to Normalise a URL and Remove Fragment

Tags: java

How to normalise a URL in Java to remove the fragment. I.e. from https://www.website.com#something to https://www.website.com

This is possible with the URL.Normalize code, although in this specific use case I've only got a full absolute URL which needs to remain intact.

I'd like to be able to modify this code slightly to remove the fragment from the URL;

```
//The website below is just an example. In reality, this URL is unknown and could be anything. Both with and without a fragment depending on the use case
URL absUrl = new URL("https://www.website.com#something");
```

My thoughts so far is that this is only going to be possible by breaking down the URL into the Protocol + Domain + Path then joining it all back together which does appear to work, but there must be a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: You could also use ``substring`` and ``indexOf`` using the ``#`` character.

Comment: The # may not always be present though so that would involve a bit more checking first. But possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to normalize a URL in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993649/how-to-normalize-a-url-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Fragments do not exist as a separate entity in Java URLs. But you can convert a URL into a URI and back to remove a fragment. I did it like this:

```
URL url;
...
if (url.toString().contains("#")) {
  URI uri = null;
  try {
    uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPath(), null);
    String file = "";
    if (uri.getPath() != null) {
      file += uri.getPath();
    }
    if (uri.getQuery() != null) {
      file += uri.getQuery();                                       
    }
    url = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), file);
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    ...
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    ...             
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment removal is fairly simple using the conversion methods `toURI` and `toURL`.  So to convert a URL to a URI:

```
URL url = /*what have you*/ …
URI u = url.toURI();
```

To remove any fragment from the URI:

```
if( u.getFragment() != null ) { // Remake with same parts, less the fragment:
    u = new URI( u.getScheme(), u.getSchemeSpecificPart(), /*fragment*/null ); }
```

In reconstructing a `URI` from its parts like that, it’s important to use the decoded getters (as shown), not the corresponding raw ones.  For authority on this usage, see e.g. the *Identity* section of the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html).

To convert the result back to a URL:

```
url = u.toURL();
```

Comment: Decoding and then re-encoding might not result in identical URIs if they contain special characters such as `+`